# PHP script not executing from Android

Tags: java, php, android

i was using HttpClient earlier to call my PHP scripts but as it always given deprecated, so I read on internet that URL is new way to do it. I am trying to implement it but script is not executing. My script sends notification on my mobile when I run it from browser, where as when calling through code, I m not getting any notification. Here is my code:

```
package jss.phpcalling;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new automessage().execute();
    }


    private class automessage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("full path of my php");

  HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.connect();
            int d = conn.getResponseCode();
            System.out.print(d);
            Log.e("Done", "Called");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

What else am I missing to make it work?

**Edit:**
updated code and removed unwanted lines, response is null, no value is being printed.

Comment: "is not working" is very generic. Tell us what didn't work as expected

Comment: I edited query, actually my php script does not run using code. it sends notification when I open it through browser, but no through code.

Comment: If you really want to get some information from the backend, return json or xml output from the php code. use parser to retrieve data to application

Comment: I just want to call php, no data is returned or send to php or server through this url.

Comment: `setDoOutput(true)` would imply that you are outputting something which by the look of things you aren't. Call `conn.setRequestMethod("GET");` to let the connection know its a 'GET'. Always call `conn.getResponseCode()` and check the code, even if you are just using it to send data so you know if anything has gone wrong.

Comment: it started working now, may be some issue was there with server. Thanks all for  support.

Answer (score 0):

I got you bro:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button send, update, restart;
private SharedPreferences speicher;
TextView tv, titel, tvScore;
final String scriptURLstring = "http://.../yourphp.php";
int score;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    init();
}

private void init() {
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tvScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tScore);


    if (internetAvalable()) { 
        sendToServer(string of what you may send to server);


    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "no connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent b = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Menu.class);
            startActivity(b);
            finish();
        }
    });

    restart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


}

public void sendToServer(final int score, final String name) {

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                String textparam = "&text1=" + URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8");

                URL scriptURL = new URL(scriptURLstring);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) scriptURL.openConnection();
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                connection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(textparam.getBytes().length);

                OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
                writer.write(textparam);
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();

                InputStream answerInputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                final String answer = getTextFromInputStream(answerInputStream);

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        tv.setText(answer);
                    }
                });
                answerInputStream.close();
                connection.disconnect();

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }).start();

}

public String getTextFromInputStream(InputStream is) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String zeile;
    try {
        while ((zeile = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(zeile + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString().trim();

}

public boolean internetAvalable() {
    ConnectivityManager cM = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo nwi = cM.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return nwi != null && nwi.isConnectedOrConnecting();
}
```

}

please ask if there is something unclear, and sorry for the mess
good luck

Comment: some of the buttons are unnecessary

Comment: and if you only want to receive, there are some modifies to made... donno what your php script looks like...